# nginx reverse proxy redirects to internal ip address

Tags: apache, nginx, nextcloud

I have a nginx as reverse proxy server and apache to server nextcloudpi web application.

i have the following as nginx config

```
server {

server_name drive.example.com;

location / {
proxy_pass http://192.168.0.7/;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
}

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/drive.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/drive.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = drive.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

server_name drive.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

and the following as apache config

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/nextcloud
ServerName drive.example.com
    CustomLog /var/log/apache2/nc-access.log combined
    ErrorLog  /var/log/apache2/nc-error.log
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/drive.example.com/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/drive.example.com/privkey.pem
  </VirtualHost>
  <Directory /var/www/nextcloud/>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride All
    <IfModule mod_dav.c>
      Dav off
    </IfModule>
    LimitRequestBody 0
    SSLRenegBufferSize 10486000
  </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Note: Previously, i had apache as the direct front end to the internet and now i want to use nginx as the front end and apache still as the web application server

Any help is appreciated if i can reach drive.example.com without redirecting to internal ip address?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you need to disable your proxy redirect headers, try changing and updating your configuration file for nginx (the reverse proxy), this will make sure that your **nginx** runs as a **middle man** between the **apache** server and the **client**, (instead of the nginx just offloading the client to the apache server with a redirect and not acting as a middle man):

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80; # if you're not using ipv6 do remove this line.    
server_name drive.example.com;

location / {
    proxy_redirect              off;
    proxy_read_timeout          1m;
    proxy_connect_timeout       1m;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;    
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://192.168.0.7/;    
}

    listen [::]:443 ssl; # if you're not using ipb6 do remove this line
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/drive.example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/drive.example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = drive.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot




server_name drive.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot   
}
```

Comment: Looks like there are some issues with this syntax. For starters, you have `proxy_redirect` twice. More importantly, there seems to be an extra `}`. I would have edited, but I'm not 100% confident in the author's original intent.